# Passing DataTable to Procedure in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to pass `DataTable` as a parameter to stored procedure in `Oracle` database.

As I was using `SQLDbType.Structured` for passing `DataTable` to `SQLServe`, but I don't find `Structured` type in `OracleDbType`. Which DataType I can use to pass `DataTable` to Oracle procedure as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, I am passing an `Associative array` to a procedure :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PACKAGE pkg_test
  3  IS
  4  TYPE typ
  5  IS
  6    TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  7    PROCEDURE P_TEST(
  8        DATASET TYP);
  9  END pkg_test;
 10  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PACKAGE BODY pkg_test
  3  IS
  4  PROCEDURE P_TEST(
  5      DATASET TYP)
  6  IS
  7  BEGIN
  8    FOR i IN 1..dataset.count
  9    LOOP
 10      dbms_output.put_line(dataset(i));
 11    END LOOP;
 12  END P_TEST;
 13  END pkg_test;
 14  /

Package body created.

SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    var_typ pkg_test.typ;
  3  BEGIN
  4    VAR_TYP(1) := 'Procedure P_TEST test';
  5    VAR_TYP(2) := 'Another test for procedure P_TEST';
  6    pkg_test.p_test(var_typ);
  7  END;
  8  /
Procedure P_TEST test
Another test for procedure P_TEST

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Update** : Did some search and found a `C#` code, not sure, but I hope it should help.

Perhaps you can do like this :

```
OracleCommand cmdOra = new OracleCommand(StoredProcedureName, Connection);
cmdOra.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();

da.InsertCommand = cmdOra;
da.Update(dsDataSet);
```

Comment: I need to pass `DataTable` from `c#` to `procedure` in `oracle`. How to do that?

Comment: You would be calling the procedure in your `C#` code, isn't it? Just call `PACKAGE.PROCURE(INPUT)`. In above answer, it would be `PKG_TEST.P_TEST(your datatable)`

Comment: Yes. I want to call procedure in `c#` with `DataTable` as input parameter.

Comment: Means I need to call `PACKAGE.PROCURE(INPUT)` using `OracleCommand`? and `CommandType` is?

Comment: `DATASET` in your example is built-in datatype? and at last line, I am looking at `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed`, is this code is for Oracle or PL/SQL?

Comment: It is `PL/SQL`. I have shown you the test case for your understanding. I believe, in `C#`, when you will be calling the procedure, you can do `pkg_test.p_test(var_typ)` where `var_typ` is the datatable. But, how to write that in `C#`, I am not sure :-(

Comment: I need for `Oracle` database :(

Comment: Yes, it is `Oracle`. I have the `package` and `procedure` written in Oracle `PL/SQL`. You will be calling this procedure via` C#` code. See my update in the answer.

Comment: I need to pass datatable, so do I need to do any changes to the code that you have given?

Comment: but its giving exception as `wrong number or types of arguments in call`

Comment: Can you update your questions and show what exactly you are passing as parameter to the procedure. Show sample data to understand the data type that you need. In my example, the data type used is for `Associative array`.

Comment: Datatype is DataTable, I want to pass C# DataTable to procedure

Comment: Read the above comment once again.